MongoDB: Add item to an array at the specified index, even if the array size is less than the index
How to insert a value to a position which is greater than the array size, the middle positions are filled with null.
Original Database:
[
  {
    "arr": ["a", "b"]
  },
  {
    "arr": ["a", "b", "c"]
  }
]

What I want (Inserting "f" at the 5th index):
[
  {
    "arr": ["a", "b", null, null, null, "f"]
  },
  {
    "arr": ["a", "b", "c", null, null, "f"]
  }
]

$push operator appends the element at the end if size is less than the position.
Also this must be done in single updateMany() call.
Found a question similar to this one, but with no answer.
What I've tried, but doesn't work:
$push: { arr: { $each: [null, null, null, null], $slice: 4 },
$push: { arr: "f" }


One of the canonical ways to do so:

append nulls to your current array.
$unwind with includeArrayIndex option to generate a field idx for the array index.
Conditionally $set the content of arr by the value of idx
trim out documents with idx larger than the index you specified
regroup the documents
$merge to update back to the collection

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      arr: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$arr",
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$range": [
                  0,
                  // your indexInput here
                  5
                ]
              },
              "as": "entry",
              "in": null
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$arr",
      includeArrayIndex: "idx"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "arr": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              "$idx",
              // your inputIdx here
              5
            ]
          },
          "then": // your input here
          "f",
          "else": "$arr"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      idx: {
        $lte: // your inputIdx here
        5
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "arr": {
        "$push": "$arr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
